# Set noindent for entire file

Tags: indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable automatic indentation on new paragraphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14375/how-to-disable-automatic-indentation-on-new-paragraphs)

Is there a way to set noindent for all paragraphs gloablly in latex, so that I do not have to manually do `\noindent` before each paragraph?

Comment: I believe this question might help you: [How to disable automatic indentation on new paragraphs?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14375/how-to-disable-automatic-indentation-on-new-paragraphs)

Comment: @yayu: nice to see that the answer helped and you marked it as accepted. I'll close this question then, as it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Set `\parindent` to `0pt` in the preamble:

```
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

Comment: Should it not be `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`? Both seem to be LaTeX notations but I thought the first pair of parentheses is necessary.

Comment: @Harrold Cavendish: the braces are not really needed for the first argument.

Comment: @Harrold: you can do both - it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Neat, thank you. I thought it would be like <br> in comparison to <br /> in HTML.

Comment: @Harrold: I think these braces are comparable to those discussed at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/why-do-people-use-unnecessary-braces

Comment: See also: [Why do people use unnecessary braces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/why-do-people-use-unnecessary-braces/1917#1917)

Comment: This does not work in the tufte-* classes: do you know a workaround?

Answer (score 23):

Set `\parindent` to `0pt` by typing

```
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`)