# Turn off indentation for some paragraphs

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I am trying to turn of the indentation for a group of paragraphs in my document. So I would like something like:

```
\begin{noindent}
Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3
\end{noindent}
```

How can I achieve this?

**P.S.** My question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27802/set-noindent-for-entire-file).

Comment: You will need to have paragraph skips if you don't want indentation of new paragraphs. But why isn't this a duplicate? Doesn't the solutions help you?

Comment: `indentation {\setlength{parskip}{0pt} no indentation} indentation` or define a simple environment (like `quotation`).

Comment: @Johannes_B, my situation is like this: N indented paragraphs, group of M not indented paragraphs and P indented paragraph (with the original indentation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just define a new environment

```
\newenvironment{zeroindent}
  {\par\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}
  {\par}
```

Then, in the document, you do

```
\begin{zeroindent}
Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3
\end{zeroindent}
```

The usefulness of this is unclear to me, though.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly strange request and a more semantically oriented markup would be preferable but without any indication of the intended use, the basic layout can be obtained by

```
indented para

\begin{parindent}0pt

no indent

no indent

\end{parindent}

indent again
```

Comment: I would not recommend this.

Comment: @egreg nor I....

Comment: Does this work? shouldn't it be `\begin{parindent}=0pt` or `\begin{parindent} 0pt`?

Comment: @Manuel see the comment under Mico's answer....

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, which uses explicit `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements to delimit the scope of `\setlength\parindent{0pt}`. (Relative to the [earlier posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27802/5001) you provided a link to, the only difference is the addition of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.) In the code, note the use blank lines before `\begingroup` and after `\endgroup`; the blank lines generate paragraph breaks.

```
Paragraph 0

\begingroup
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3
\endgroup

Paragraph 4
```

Comment: ooops sorry I'm an idiot:-)