# \noindent for whole document without \parindent=0

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I'm writing a Cheatsheet with a lot of formulas and having paragraphs indent is just wasting space and doesn't look good at all, so I want to disable autoindentation. But sometimes I still want indentation in some cases (which aren't rare, but still rarer than I would type `\noindent` without any changes).

So far I've found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27802/set-noindent-for-entire-file), which in both answers says to use

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

But this prevents me from using `\indent` when I want it. So the actual questions would be. Is there a way for latex to default to `\noindent` and then use `\indent` when necessary?

Edit: I'd also like to add that I'm still very new to typesetting, so if what I'm asking for is bad practice, please let me know, and if possible, why.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Instead of `\indent` use `\hspace*{20pt}` (no space after it.

Comment: Comment aside: it's better to load the `parskip` package,  which sets `\arindent` to 0pt AND adds some vertical skip between paragraphs,  taking care of the vertical spacing in lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code saves the original meaning of `\indent` and redefines it.
Inside a group it sets `\parindent` to the original value and calls the saved `\indent`:

```
\let\SavedIndent\indent
\protected\def\indent{%
  \begingroup
    \parindent=\the\parindent
    \SavedIndent
  \endgroup
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

Thus, like the original `\indent` the redefined indent starts a new paragraph if it is called in vertical mode. But it will not set the space in horizontal mode like the original.