# text before and after itemized are not align under subsection

Tags: itemize

I tries to add some text before and after using `itemize`. However, they are not aligned. How to align after text with before text?

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{A-A}
before text
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item b
\end{itemize}
after text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) You could try with `\noindent before text` but this is not the behaviour of the standard classes. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, possibly starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does `\noindent` or `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` in the preamble [help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27802/set-noindent-for-entire-file)?

Comment: It aligns properly with `article` class.. which class are you using?? Add a mwe.

Comment: I used `ctexart `. I found it also works. but they are left aligned with section number. It works if I use `flushleft`. but how if there anyway I can add the indent?

Comment: Post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and we might be able to help you. Something defines the section titles to not prevent the first paragraph to be indented, which is not the default behaviour of the standard classes. But without compilable code which results in the above picture, we can not help you any further (at least I won't and most other users most likely also won't).

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for your suggestion. I edit the picture the code, which was exactly same with what it ran

Answer (score 1):

The `ctexart` sets the indent after the section title in `\@startsection`. There should be a key to change the behaviour, but sadly I don't understand Chinese, and the documentation seems to be in Chinese. The key should be anything related to the word `afterindent`, if you understand the documentation search for that.

Therefore the following hacks its way through `ctexart`:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@startsection{\@afterindenttrue}{\@afterindentfalse}{}
  {%
    \GenericError{}{Patching \noexpand\@startsection failed}{}
    {Read the manual of 'ctexart' and search for the key 'afterindent'.}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{A-A}
before text
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item b
\end{itemize}
after text
\end{document}
```