# Removing an indent (when \noindent won't work)

Tags: indentation

I am using a CV template that indents all text within a section (the template can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/shaila-angs-cv/zhxksygkzfds)). I want to remove the indents, and my 'solution' has been to repeatedly type `\hspace{-0.8em}`. Surely there is a better way?

**UPDATE:** A minimal working example is here:

```
\documentclass{resume}

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf University of Sydney} \hfill {\em 2013-2019} \\

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

As one can check, neither `\noindent` nor `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` fix the problem...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set noindent for entire file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27802/set-noindent-for-entire-file)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- unfortunately, it doesn't work. I'll add a minimal working example to the question so it's easier to others to understand what's going on

Comment: Can someone explain to me why the question has been closed? As I have explained, the solution to the `duplicate' question does *not* work.

Comment: @afreelunch: I'd suggest editing the `resume.cls` class inside your template. Find the definition of the `rSection` environment and you'll note that it issues a `list` environment with `\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}`. Change that to `\setlength{\leftmargin}{0em}` and you'll see the change.

Answer (score 2):

Try `\noindent` for the line or if want no indent at all set in the preamble
`\setlength\parindent{0pt}`.

Comment: Hi Oni, thanks for the idea. However, this unfortunately doesn't fix the problem (I have now posted a MWE to make it easier to see what works and what doesn't)