# Removing an indent (when \noindent doesn't work)

Tags: indentation

I am using a CV template that indents all text within a section (the template can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/shaila-angs-cv/zhxksygkzfds)). I want to remove the indents, and my 'solution' has been to repeatedly type `\hspace{-0.8em}`. Surely there is a better way?

I have tried doing this using `\noindent` or `\setlength\parindent{0pt}`. However, neither of these seem to eliminate the indent (I'm not sure why...) Below is an example which includes `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` but nonetheless has an indent.

```
\documentclass{resume}

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf University of Sydney} \hfill {\em 2013-2019} \\

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

Note: I recently asked this question but it was closed because it is allegedly answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27802/set-noindent-for-entire-file). However, the solution to that question was to use `\noindent` or `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` - and the whole point of my question is that these don't seem to work here! So I'm not sure why the question was closed... (and there doesn't seem to be any way for me to reverse this except to repost the question).

Comment: For future reference: if a question is closed as a duplicate but the referenced question does not provide a good answer, then you can edit your closed question to add an explanation why the solution in the duplicate did not work. An edit on a closed question causes the question to be put in a reopen queue where high-reputation members of the site can decide to reopen the question. If you do that, make sure that it is extremely clear why the duplicate was not useful - more than just "the duplicate didn't work", but a full minimal example, preferably with the solution of the duplicate applied,

Comment: and a description of the result and why that was not what you wanted. Note also that putting the question in the reopen queue only works for the first edit after closing, afterwards high-reputation members can still put the question in the queue manually but that doesn't happen often so make sure the first edit is complete and clear. In any case, it is not really necessary to post the question again as a new question, that might even work out badly if the new question is again closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment `rSection` is defined by

```
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}
```

so the indent is wanted. By the way, the class also does

```
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
```

so there's no point in adding again `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`.

You can redefine the environment as

```
\documentclass{resume}

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry}

\renewenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}% Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{rSection}{Education}
\textbf{University of Sydney} \hfill \emph{2013-2019}
\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

Please, note that `\bf` and the similar two-letter font changing commands have been deprecated for almost 30 years. It's quite surprising that a class written in 2010 still uses them. I changed the code to a better one, but the rest of the class should probably be modified as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is incredibly helpful!