# Paragraph numbering in the margin + line numbering (using reledmac)

Tags: numbering, paragraphs, layout, reledmac

I would like to have the paragraph number in the right margin (preferably without a full stop after it; and without indentation of the text) At the same time, I would like to have line numbering that starts from the beginning of each paragraph.

I have two MWEs. In the first example, the numbers are correct, but I don't like the layout (as mentioned: indentation, full stop, position).
In the second example, the paragraph numbers are in the right place, but I can't get rid of the indentation and full stop and the line numbering does not start from the beginning in paragraph 2 but runs through.

I'd appreciate any ideas!

**MWE 1**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lineation{pstart}

\numberpstarttrue
\beginnumbering
\autopar Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.
text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.

\autopar Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.
text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

**MWE 1 compiled:**
[image: MWE 1]

**MWE 2**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\newcommand{\mpstart}{\pstart \ledsidenote{\thepstart}}

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lineation{mpstart} % not working!

\beginnumbering
\mpstart Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.
text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.\pend

\mpstart Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.
text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.\pend

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

**MWE 2 compiled:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your first example more promising. The approach with `\numberpstarttrue` is more native than "hacking" `\lineation{}` to take a new kind of argument, as in the second example. So let's start from that.

1. The [documentation, p. 148-9](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/reledmac.pdf#page=148) shows what `reledmac` does when you invoke `\numberpstarttrue`: it prints `\thepstart` at paragraph begin.
   In turn, here's the line that determines *how* that counter is displayed:

```
\renewcommand{\thepstart}{{\bfseries\@arabic\c@pstart}. }
```

You can copy this `\renewcommand` into your preamble and modify it to suit your needs (see the example below).

2. To suppress all paragraph indentation, [you can write](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27802/set-noindent-for-entire-file) `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` in your preamble (this is true in (La)TeX at large).

[**Another suggestion**: You don't have to repeat `\autopar` with every new paragraph, in fact, the point is to spare you the hassle of typing `\pend \pstart` with every new paragraph. Use it just once, right after `\beginnumbering`, and you'll be fine.]

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\numberpstarttrue
\lineation{pstart}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thepstart}{\ledsidenote{\bfseries\@arabic\c@pstart}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\beginnumbering
\autopar 
Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.
text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.

Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.
text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of 
text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.Paragraph of text.

\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That really helped.

Comment: Glad that it did :)