# Should I put the name of a new command in braces?

Tags: macros, best-practices, braces, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do people use unnecessary braces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/why-do-people-use-unnecessary-braces)

In so far as I know, the open and close braces around the command name for

```
\newcommand{\commandname}{...}
```

versus

```
\newcommand\commandname{...}
```

seem to be a matter of personal preference or *style*? Is there a consensus on this issue and if so what is it?

Comment: I think it is just a style issue. I prefer the first, but know that many others refer the second.  The second is needed when an `\def`, `\edef`, `\xdef`, `\let` are used.

Comment: The same applies here: [How bad for TeX is omitting braces {}, even if the result is the same?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82329)

Comment: @hsmyers Please let us know via comments if the linked questions do not address your issue. If the answers there apply to your case, then this question will be closed to keep the place tidy.

Comment: Close away @Vivi, it seems to be pretty much as I thought. While I have no particular preference, I just noticed the current WIP (Work In Progress) had gotten a tiny bit inconsistent and before I normalized my macros I thought I'd ask the question. Went with leaving them out BTW.