# Usage of curly braces in math mode for macros

Tags: math-mode, sourcecode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do people use unnecessary braces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/why-do-people-use-unnecessary-braces)
>   [How bad for TeX is omitting braces {}, even if the result is the same?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82329/how-bad-for-tex-is-omitting-braces-even-if-the-result-is-the-same)

I wanted to know what is the preffered way of writing macros which accept parameters. So what is a more correct way: `\frac 1 2` or `\frac{1}{2}`?

I think that the former should be preffered in most cases, as the code will work if there is only one symbol and it especially help the readability of code in cases of `$\vec e_i$` instead of `$\vec{e}_i$` as `$\vec{e_i}$` would not typeset the math correctly.

So what do people usually do in such cases?

Comment: Teaching `\frac 1 2` to newbies can make them think that `\frac 1 10` is good input.

Comment: It's most of the time, the braced version that should be adopted.

Comment: To me, `\vec e_i` makes it look like `\vec` applies to all of `e_i`, as if it were `\vec{e_i}`.  But, as you note, `\vec e_i` actually typesets the same as `\vec{e}_i`, *not* `\vec{e_i}`.

Comment: @tohecz Yes it is. Sorry for duplicating a question.

Comment: {always use braces}

Comment: @gns-ank No worries, as long as you don't mind this one getting closed as a duplicate.