# Is the preferred use of tilde command with braces?

Tags: braces, syntax, tilde

It looks like the standard way of using the `\tilde` is as in `$\tilde{a}$`. However, I saw a latex document in which the usage was `$\tilde a$`.

Will the two ways of defining a tilde produce the same results? Is there a recommended way of using it?

Comment: Since there is no curly bracket after the macro `\tilde`, the first character `a` is taken. So the result will be identical. I think it is about the personal taste. I would use `\tilde{a}` for clarity. But I always use `\frac12` instead of `\frac{1}{2}` for simplicity.

Comment: Mostly [macros - Why do people use unnecessary braces? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/why-do-people-use-unnecessary-braces).