# Command that expands to `{ <output> }` instead of `<output>`

Tags: expl3, expansion, xparse

I'd like to define a command which expands to `{ <output> }` instead of `<output>`. I've tried wrapping the command contents with additional

- `{` / `}`
- `\bgroup` / `\egroup`
- `\begingroup` / `\endgroup`
- `\group_begin:` / `\group_end:`
- `\c_group_begin_token` / `\c_group_end_token`
- `\str_use:N \c_left_brace_str` / `\str_use:N \c_right_brace_str`

but to no avail.

My use case: I'd like to be able to write `\R[1][2]` instead of `\mathbb{R}^{1 \times 2}`, but also be able to use this in subscripts and superscripts, like `0_\R[1][2]`, without needing to surround it with braces. I know, this is rather specific and maybe lazy, but I'm honestly also just curious about this from a TeXnical point of view.

Simplified MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareDocumentCommand { \R } { o }
  {
    \mathbf { R }
    \IfValueT { #1 } { \sp { #1 } }
  }

\DeclareDocumentCommand { \Q } { m }
  {
    \mathbf { Q } \sp { #1 }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  $0_\R$    % throws error "Missing } inserted"
  $0_\R[2]$ % throws error "Missing } inserted"
  $0_\Q{2}$ % expands to $0_\mathbf{Q}^{2}$, not $0_{\mathbf{Q}^{2}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: using braces for super and subscripts is a feature it's really unfortunate that some horrors like `x_\text{aaa}` sort of half work and don't give an error

Comment: You can not have a trailing optional argument via an expandable command and to make you `o_\R...` work `\R` needs to expand to a brace group, so it's quite hard to do what you want but would be trivial but bad practice if `\R` had a mandatory `{}` argument rather than `[]`

Comment: sorry I only fixed \R in my original answer just spotted you wanted \Q as well, updated.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When you say that `x_\text{aaa}` sort of "half" works, are you just referring to the fact that it's not good practice (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82338/170958), or is there actually any "functional" difference between `x_\text{aaa}` and `x_{\text{aaa}}`, specifically? My understanding was that those code snippets would be equivalent to `x\sb\text{aaa}` and `x\sb{\text{aaa}}`, respectively, and that those two are essentially equivalent to one another (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1929/170958).

Comment: the parsing is completely specific to sub and super, you can't do `\fbox\text{aaa}` it has to be `\fbox{\text{aaa}}` so if anything tries to redefine ^ as an active macro with a normal `#1` style argument, it'll fail. and it's a bad habit to get in to, if you have `\def\foo{abc}` and do `\fbox\foo` that is `\fbox{abc}`  but `x^\foo`  is `x^{a}bc`  as `^` expands tokens looking for `{` (which is why the answers work) but is almost never what you want and `x^{abc}` was intended but you get the wrong thing with no warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the command to expand to a brace group, but super and subscripts should *always* be braced.

```
\documentclass{article}

% only needed in old latex releases \usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Please don't do this
\DeclareDocumentCommand\R{}{\bgroup\Rinner}

\DeclareDocumentCommand { \Rinner } { o }
  {
    \mathbf { R }
    \IfValueT { #1 } { \sp { #1 }}
    \egroup
  }

\DeclareDocumentCommand { \Q } { m }
  {
    {\mathbf { Q } \sp { #1 }}
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  $0_\R$    % throws error "Missing } inserted"
  $0_\R[2]$ % throws error "Missing } inserted"
  $0_\Q{2}$ % expands to $0_\mathbf{Q}^{2}$, not $0_{\mathbf{Q}^{2}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see — I had just gotten used to shortcuts like `a_\text{b}`, but I appreciate that they're not best practice, and will stick with manually adding braces. But I really appreciate your answer, it makes sense. Does that mean that `\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{}{...}` and `\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{}{{...}}` (or `\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{}{\bgroup...\egroup}`) will always have identical behavior, because the additional braces are gobbled / ignored (if they are matched up at least, unlike with `\bgroup\Rinner`)?

Answer (score 3):

I'd avoid being lazy about braces. Laziness is good in other places.

For instance, you should define some `\numberset` command in order to achieve uniformity in how the symbols are typeset (and you can later decide to change all of them in one sweep).

You shouldn't be using `\DeclareDocumentCommand`, anyway: you risk to redefine without warning an important command.

Now the abstraction:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\numberset}{m}{\mathbf{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vecspace}{m}{\bgroup\VECSPACE{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\VECSPACE}{moo}{%
  #1%
  \IfValueT{#2}{^{#2\IfValueT{#3}{\times #3}}}%
  \egroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\R}{}{\vecspace{\numberset{R}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Q}{}{\vecspace{\numberset{Q}}}

\begin{document}

$0_\R$
$0_\R[2]$
$0_\R[2][3]$

$0_\Q$
$0_\Q[2]$
$0_\Q[2][3]$

$0_\vecspace{V}[1][2]$

$0_\vecspace{\numberset{J}}[1][2]$

\end{document}
```

This way you can accommodate occasional different situations.

However, I insist that

```
0_{\R[2]}
```

is ***much*** better and doesn't cost too much. For this you just remove one layer:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\vecspace}{moo}{%
  #1%
  \IfValueT{#2}{^{#2\IfValueT{#3}{\times #3}}}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the recommendations regarding best practices, I really appreciate it. I've gotten used to notational shortcuts, which I do believe can be very useful and have their place, but it's good to know where to draw the line, so to speak.